# How Do I Adjust PHP Forms

Tags: php

I am an extreme newbie with PHP forms. I was just introduced to them a couple days ago, started researching and found a tutorial that was perfect for a novice, but I'm completely lost when it comes to adjustments.

The two issues I have with the code below is that I don't want the subject to be automatic, because the form will be used for several reason. I also don't know what those "headers" are. I don't want  to give my email to people using the form.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<form action="send-mail.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain" name="contact-form">
                    <!--RECOMMENDED TO USE POST METHOD FOR SENSITIVE DATA-->


                    <div id="floatLeft">    <!--TO ALLOW FOR SIDE X SIDE BOXES AS SCREEN SIZE INCREASES-->

                       <!--NAME BOX-->
                        <p><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" autocomplete="off" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('This Field Cannot Be Left Blank')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required >
                        <small class="error"></small></p>

                        <!--EMAIL BOX-->
                        <p><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please Enter A Valid Email')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" autocomplete="off" required>
                        <small class="error"></small></p>


                        <!--PHONE BOX-->
                        <p><input type="tel" name="telephone" onBlur='addDashes(this)'  placeholder="Phone (no dashes)" pattern='^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$' oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Minimum length is 10 digits')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" autocomplete="off" required>
                        <small class="error"></small></p>


                        <!--SUBJECT BOX-->
                        <p><input id="subject" type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" pattern=".{3,}" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Must Enter A Minimum of 3 Characters')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required></p>

                        <div class="clear"></div> <!--//////  Necessary to properly push comments box to next line   ////////-->

                    </div>

                    <div id="floatRight">   <!--TO ALLOW FOR SIDE X SIDE BOXES AS SCREEN SIZE INCREASES-->

                        <!--FREEFORM BOX-->
                        <p><textarea name="comments" cols="110" rows="12" placeholder="Message" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('This Field Cannot Be Left Blank')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required></textarea></p>
                        <p><input type="submit" onClick='addDashes(this.form)' value="Send"></p>

                    </div>

                    </form>
```

Here's my PHP code:

```
<?php
$mail_to = 'email@email.com'; // specify your email here

// Assigning data from the $_POST array to variables
$name = $_POST['name'];
$mail_from = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['telephone'];
$message = $_POST['comments'];

// Construct email subject
$subject = 'www.mysite.com Message from visitor ' . $name;

// Construct email body
$body_message = 'From: ' . $name . "\r\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: ' . $mail_from . "\r\n";
$body_message .= 'Phone: ' . $phone . "\r\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: ' . $message;

// Construct email headers
$headers = 'From: ' . $mail_from . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $mail_from . "\r\n";

$mail_sent = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_sent == true){ ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Thank you for the message. I will get back to you shortly.');
    window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php } else { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Message not sent. Please, notify the site administrator email@email.com');
    window.location = 'index.html';
</script>
<?php
}  ?>
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: I am not using Bootstrap. I never did use that before. Until now, my site was only HTML, CSS and JS.

Comment: In your place I would consider using it. It is simple and helps a lot when it comes to adjust forms.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing subject by getting the post.  You may want to remove the construct email subject if you don't want it to start with the site.

I don't think I understand the giving people your email part of the question.

```
$subject = $_POST['subject'];

// Construct email subject
$subject = 'www.mysite.com Message - ' . $subject;
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a try.

Comment: For the email - Basically, I don't anyone accessing the site to be able to get my email. I don't want to open myself up to spam. Like I said, I'm completely new to this, so if I'm explaining wrong, or not understanding how email forms work, I apologize.

Comment: I assume the mail to in the php code would be where you store your email.  When the server serves the page to the user it shouldn't display anything in the <?php    ?> sections.  You can view the source of the page after it loads on the server to make sure it is serving it correctly and verify you can't see your email.

Answer (score 0):

Ed de Almeida...i dont think it has any thing to do with bootstrap.

if i get you correctly, you want
1. the subjects to be dynamic
2. you want to understand the header workings?

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// You specify the email you want to recieve your message. This way, no one wud see the email because it is server side and would not be visible to all
    $mail_to = 'email@email.com'; 





// Assigning data from the $_POST array to variables and clear it of every possible intrusuin. Just make this a tradition ok?
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['nname']));
    $mail_from = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['email']));
    $phone = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['telephone']));
    $message = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['comments']));
    $subject = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['subject']));

    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
      $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
      $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

      // Create email headers The format below. gives you a perfect arrangment

      $headers .= 'From: '.'www.mysite.com Message from visitor '.$name .'<'.$mail_from.'>'."\r\n".
                 'Reply-To: '.$mail_from."\r\n" .
                 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

        // Construct email body
        $body_message = 'From: ' . $name . "\r\n";
        $body_message .= 'E-mail: ' . $mail_from . "\r\n";
        $body_message .= 'Phone: ' . $phone . "\r\n";
        $body_message .= 'Message: ' . $message;    

        // Construct email subject
        $subjectToSend = 'message subject:' . $subject;

        $mail_sent = mail($mail_to, $subjectToSend, $body_message, $headers);

        if ($mail_sent == true){ 
        ?>
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            alert('Thank you for the message. I will get back to you shortly.');
            window.location = 'index.html';
            </script>
         <?php } else { ?>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            alert('Message not sent. Please, notify the site administrator email@email.com');
            window.location = 'index.html';
        </script>
        <?php    }  ?>

<?php }?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="send-mail.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain" name="contact-form">
                    <!--RECOMMENDED TO USE POST METHOD FOR SENSITIVE DATA-->


                    <div id="floatLeft">    <!--TO ALLOW FOR SIDE X SIDE BOXES AS SCREEN SIZE INCREASES-->

                       <!--NAME BOX-->
                        <p><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" autocomplete="off" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('This Field Cannot Be Left Blank')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required >
                        <small class="error"></small></p>

                        <!--EMAIL BOX-->
                        <p><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please Enter A Valid Email')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" autocomplete="off" required>
                        <small class="error"></small></p>


                        <!--PHONE BOX-->
                        <p><input type="tel" name="telephone" onBlur='addDashes(this)'  placeholder="Phone (no dashes)" pattern='^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$' oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Minimum length is 10 digits')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" autocomplete="off" required>
                        <small class="error"></small></p>


                        <!--SUBJECT BOX-->
                        <p><input id="subject" type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" pattern=".{3,}" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Must Enter A Minimum of 3 Characters')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required></p>

                        <div class="clear"></div> <!--//////  Necessary to properly push comments box to next line   ////////-->

                    </div>

                    <div id="floatRight">   <!--TO ALLOW FOR SIDE X SIDE BOXES AS SCREEN SIZE INCREASES-->

                        <!--FREEFORM BOX-->
                        <p><textarea name="comments" cols="110" rows="12" placeholder="Message" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('This Field Cannot Be Left Blank')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required></textarea></p>
                        <p><input type="submit" onClick='addDashes(this.form)' value="Send" name="submit"></p>

                    </div>

                    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Correct. That is what I'm looking for.

Comment: i wud work out somthing for you shortly! trying the codes perfect for u. pls give me a few min Brenda813

Comment: No problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi brenda. Try the code i posted. It should work. I only have a problem with your choice of Javascript as a success message. if it gives u problem. we must change dat